# Magento 2 : Create a JOIN

Tags: magento2, product, database, grid, filter

I am trying to display a report which

GROUP BY : SKU and  Subsidiary.

So instead of displaying each RMA in different rows,

I am trying to display Filtered Report,  Group by SKU
and 2nd group by Subsidiary  (CA / DE).

I have used two tables for it.
(i.e mst_rma_rma & mst_rma_item)

[image]

[image]

**Current grid :**
[image]

**Desired grid :**
[image]

I have customized Mirasvit Rma module for this.

Here are the modules - https://easyupload.io/8e4jbp.

Is there any way I can display the data in a grid-like the desired grid?

Any thoughts appreciated.
Kindly let me know if any further details are required.

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: for solution of this problem we have to use left join query to combine two tables and specify product sku in group by in query.

Comment: Hello @DeepShah, would be great if you can add a query as answer.

Comment: Hello @HamendraSunthwal I am going to share link with you it will help you to create join query : https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-join-2-tables-magento-2.html#overview-of-joining-data-between-2-tables-in-magento-2

Comment: this is the actual query in which they want to get data from sales order and payment table: $this->sales_order_table = "main_table";
    $this->sales_order_payment_table = $this->getTable("sales_order_payment");
    $this->getSelect()
        ->join(array('payment' =>$this->sales_order_payment_table), $this->sales_order_table . '.entity_id= payment.parent_id',
        array('payment_method' => 'payment.method',
            'order_id' => $this->sales_order_table.'.entity_id'
        )
    );
    $this->getSelect()->where("payment_method=".$payment_method);

Answer (score 1):

```
public function getJoinData(){
   $collection = $this->_helloModelFactory->create()->getCollection();
   $second_table_name = $this->_resource->getTableName('second_table_name'); 
   $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('second' => $second_table_name),
                                               'main_table.id = second.customer_id');
   echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString(); 
   exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not to use subselect to `eav_attribute` and hardcode attribute table. For any manipulations with EAV attribute use `\Magento\Eav\Model\Config` instance.

Second, you should be careful with link field between entity and their attributes. You should use `\Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool` and `\Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityMetadataInterface` for link them.

Example for correct way of join product attribute

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/Model/ResourceModel/Example/Collection.php**

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Model\ResourceModel\Example;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config as EavConfig;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityMetadataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * @var EavConfig
     */
    protected $eavConfig;

    /**
     * @var EntityMetadataInterface
     */
    protected $metadata;

    public function __construct(
        EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        EavConfig $eavConfig,
        MetadataPool $metadataPool,
        AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->metadata  = $metadataPool->getMetadata(ProductInterface::class);

        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();

        $attribute  = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Product::ENTITY, 'manufacturer');
        $tableAlias = sprintf('t_%s', $attribute->getAttributeCode());
        $linkField  = $this->metadata->getLinkField();
        $fieldAlias = $attribute->getAttributeCode();

        // e is alias for catalog_product_entity
        $this->getSelect()->joinInner(
            [$tableAlias => $attribute->getBackendTable()],
            sprintf('e.%1$s = %2$s.%1$s AND %2$s.attribute_id = %3$d AND %2$s.store_id = 0',
                $linkField, $tableAlias, $attribute->getId()),
            [$fieldAlias => 'value']
        );

        return $this;
    }
}
```

P.S. Use `catalog_product_entity` as main table and join result (attributes) to. Bad idea to use attribute table and use `left join` for parent table

**[UPDATE]**

I keep original answer to original question, maybe it will be helpful for someone

I see 2 ways to implement desired grid in magento. I don't have a time to implement solution based on 3rd party extension, but i fast review how it built and how it works.

You cannot reuse exists grid with exists data provider because it's based on another one logic to load data.

### **1. Using Listing Component**

**Create Data Provider and register it**

First of all you need to have data provide which implement `\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchResultsInterface`.

You can create DB collection based on RMA Item Collection and use RMA Item Resource. In following example used some custom resource model `Acme\StackExchange\Model\ResourceModel\Report` which describe item table and connection.

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Model\ResourceModel\Report;

use Acme\StackExchange\Model\ResourceModel\Report as ReportResource;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\AggregationInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchResultsInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection implements SearchResultsInterface
{
    /**
     * @var AggregationInterface
     */
    protected AggregationInterface $aggregations;

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();

        $this->_init(Document::class, ReportResource::class);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();

        // ideally to reset extra data and keep only needed like
        $this->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
        $this->getSelect()->columns([
            'product_sku',
        ], 'main_table');

        // join your rma table to rma_item as main_table and load related data
        $this->getSelect()->join(
            ['rma' => $this->getTable('rma_entity')],
            'main_table.rma_id = rma.rma_id',
            'subsidiary'
        )
        ->group('main_table.product_sku, rma.subsidiary');
        // don't select your extra table fields here

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    protected function _getItemId(DataObject $item)
    {
        return implode('-', [
            $item->getData('product_sku'),
            $item->getData('subsidiary'),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @return AggregationInterface
     */
    public function getAggregations(): AggregationInterface
    {
        return $this->aggregations;
    }

    /**
     * @param AggregationInterface $aggregations
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setAggregations(AggregationInterface $aggregations)
    {
        $this->aggregations = $aggregations;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function setItems(array $items)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getSearchCriteria()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function setSearchCriteria(SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria)
    {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getTotalCount(): int
    {
        return (int)$this->getSize();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function setTotalCount($totalCount)
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Alternative is create collection without interface implementation and create virtual collection for data provider

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Acme\StackExchange\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Grid\Collection"
                 type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">rma_item_table</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Acme\StackExchange\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Collection</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="acme_rma_report_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Acme\StackExchange\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Listing and UI Column**

Next step is create UI listing for your grid and specify your extra data as custom column

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="listing_columns">
        <column name="extra"  class="Acme\StackExchange\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Extra">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Extra</label>
                <bodyTmpl>ui/grid/cells/html</bodyTmpl>
                <sortable>false</sortable>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Example of Listing Column Component for load data

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns;

class Extra extends Columns
{
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource): array
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                // you need to get sku and subsidiary from item
                // receive list of related items
                // you can use repository or collection for get data by sku and subsidiary
                // you need to generate HTML fragment of table to show
                // set result to related field

                $item[$this->getName()] = 'your result HTML here';
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

### **2. Using old style Magento Grid (used in report)**

General idea is prepare special collection which populate data in specific format

You need to create collection which loads the same data like in first example, but you don't need to implements `Magento\Framework\Api\SearchResultsInterface` and use `Document` model as item. You need to use `\Magento\Reports\Model\Item` or implement some of methods. You need to implement after load logic in your collection for load extra data

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Model\ResourceModel\Report;

// ...
class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    protected function _afterLoad()
    {
        // you can collect all available sku in result and load data for those sku
        // or load data for each item individually
        // you need to set children (iterable) with any DataObject instances 
        foreach ($this->_items as $item) {
            $children = [];
            // your logic to load or add children to array
            $item->setChildren($children);
        }

        return parent::_afterLoad();
    }
}
```

Create layout with grid container, grid using default templates or customize.

*NOTE:* Your grid block should be extends from `\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended` and you need to set your collection and all fields from both tables.

Also you need to set `_groupedColumn` property as list of general fields or add them individually with `$this->isColumnGrouped('sku', true);`

As result you will get grid with rowspans for grouped fields

Comment: Hello, I am already using two tables in same function (i.e _initSelect) how to manage the attribute join within it ?

Comment: Can you please advise ?

Comment: It's a very abstract question. Please update your question with details. For example, you can add your field to map with `$this->addFilterToMap('fieldAlias', 'tableAlias.realField');` and use manipulation like `$collection->addFieldToFilter('fieldAlias', ['eq' => 'value']);` outside of collection, etc.

Comment: Hello Victor, I have updated my question.
Please refer it & advise me.
Thank you.

Comment: I've updated comment and spent some time for explain and hope concept can help you

Comment: Hello @VictorTihonchuk, thank you for the answer & the explanation but I am really looking for a way to get data in such a way that it has a single SKU for the single subsidiary.

Comment: Did you really try any of methods which i've described? I've added important comments in code what you need to add and how

Comment: Hello @VictorTihonchuk, the answer does not relate to the question.

Comment: Hello @HamendraSunthwal, my answer contains from 2 parts and one right now is not related to edited question. You can see original question https://magento.stackexchange.com/revisions/118b09d8-4a77-497d-b030-4c7f310130e7/view-source

Comment: @VictorTihonchuk the one that we are currently looking at its different question so we should answer to that question not a revised one.

Comment: @Devhs Please see section after **[UPDATE]** and let me know if the answer related to updated one question? I can remove everything before if you think it's need to do.